# How can I take snapshot of the whole context I drew in quartz 2d

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I want to take a thumbnail preview of what the user will watch on clicking a button. Or if this is not possible is it possible to scale a context to a particular size. 
My context is currently using full screen i.e 1004x768 px . And I want this whole context to come in 300x300 px without loosing its identity.

Comment: Is you context bitmap context?

Comment: No, My context is 
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

Comment: You need to add more information in question on how may context are there, which is doing what.. and which context you want to update. If you are doing this with only one context you may have to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
             UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width));

            [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ];
            UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            NSLog(@"Screen Shot : %@",screenshot);
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


            // ATTACHING A SCREENSHOT
            NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot);

            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

            NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [df setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
        NSString *timestamp = [df stringFromDate:date];
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fullImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%@.png",timestamp]];
        NSLog(@"TimeStamp = %@",timestamp);

            NSLog(@"Image Path : %@",fullImagePath);
            [myData writeToFile:fullImagePath atomically:YES];
```